# How do I find the revision of my local working copy

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How to know at which revision my local copy of the repository was downloaded from the server? (I usually use CornerStore and I cannot find this option in tortoisesvn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Show Log option or in properties of this file, in Subversion tab.

Comment: I have found it, I have notice in tortoisesvn current version is in bold... :-)